# What is the weight difference between ASICS GEL-KAYANO 20 and ASICS GEL-KAYANO 20 LITE-SHOW?

Tags: equipment, running

Google all around the web and cant find exact information, it only says the second model is more lightweight, but no precise grams or oz's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lite-Show is not a more lightweight version of the Kayano 20, it's a glow-in-the-dark / more-reflective version of the Kayano 20.

(Source - I'm sitting next to a warehouse with both versions of the shoe and I compared them.)